# Wordpress | Sub-domain switching

Tags: multi-language, subdomains

I'm finding a way to redirect to a sub-domain. Sub-domains contain instances of multiple languages, say for an example -:

`http://mysite/?p=7694`

This is the English site and I want it to redirect to (when user selects particular language)

```
http://chinese.mysite/?p=7694
```

Is there a simple way of doing this want to know if there are any plugins to do so. This the requirement of my client, and they wont to do it in that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/), this WordPress plugin let you have an easy to use interface for managing a fully multilingual web site.

> One-Click-Switching between the
> languages - Change the language as
> easy as switching  Choose one of 3
> Modes to make your URLs pretty and
> SEO-friendly. - The everywhere
> compatible ?lang=en, simple and
> beautiful /en/foo/ or nice and neat
> en.yoursite.com One language for each
> URL - Users and SEO will thank you for
> not mixing multilingual content

For reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

Comment: Wow, you probably just saved my life. qTranslate looks amazing. Finally a way to hand over tedious translation updating work to my customers themselves :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP Subdomains](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-subdomains/) its a plugin for WordPress that allows you to setup your main categories, pages and authors as subdomains.